# How to get Count of Items in a Folder using MediaStore Android

Tags: android, mediastore

I have a directory with images in it . I want to know how to get number of images from that folder using MediaStore . I tried using COUNT keyword but that is not supported in AndroidQ . Also please let know if there are alternate efficient ways of doing so .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this way

```
 private static int getCount(@NonNull final Context context, @NonNull final Uri contentUri, @NonNull final String bucketId)
    {
        try (final Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri,
                null, MediaStore.Video.Media.BUCKET_ID + "=?", new String[]{bucketId}, null))
        {
            return ((cursor == null) || (cursor.moveToFirst() == false)) ? 0 : cursor.getCount();
        }
    }



final HashMap<String, AlbumQuery.Album> output = new HashMap<>();
        final Uri contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        final String[] projection = {MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.BUCKET_ID,MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME,MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.DATA};
        try (final Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri, projection, null, null, null))
        {
            if ((cursor != null) && (cursor.moveToFirst() == true))
            {
                final int columnBucketName = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME);
                final int columnBucketId   = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.BUCKET_ID);
                do
                {
                    final String bucketId   = cursor.getString(columnBucketId);
                    final String bucketName = cursor.getString(columnBucketName);
                    if (output.containsKey(bucketName) == false)
                    {
                        final int count = AlbumQuery.getCount(context, contentUri, bucketId);
                        //output.put(bucketName, album);
                    }

                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
        }




**Another way**

 fun count(dir: File) {
        try {
            if (dir.isDirectory) {
                if(!dir.name.equals(AppConstants.MASK_DIR_LOCAL) && !dir.name.equals(DIR1) && !dir.name.equals(DIR2) ){
                    val children = dir.list()
                    for (i in children.indices) {
                        //File(dir, children[i])
                            count++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }catch (e:java.lang.Exception){
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where to get bucketId from ?

Comment: Bucket id is in mediastore.video.media.bucketid, you can put this in projection array which use with contentresolver.query and get by using the cursor.columnindexid and cursor.getstring

Comment: Can you update the above code to replicate what you have said . It is bit unclear to understand .

Comment: Please check the line of code, i have updated it

Comment: Which one is more efficient : MediaStore or iterative Searching ?

Comment: If you know the folder name with path then prefer to use iterator just with File object, you can also use the mediastore by bucketid with filter through displayname with selection param in contentresolver.query.

Comment: Okay , will try and revert

Comment: I guess , querying a database must be quick than querying a fileSystem which is a perk of having a database.